Error on running with layout_method="trivial" on qiskit 1.1.0
The layout_method="trivial" which is one of the parameter for the pass manager is always providing a errored result even on statevector simulator.
Im trying to run the following circuit on statevector simulator and it gives 01 state as expected for 2078 shots. But the same circuit run with layout_method="trivial" is giving me errors in the calculation. When i run the same circuit on different fake backends its the same results.
qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
qc.x(0)
#qc.measure(0,0)
#qc.measure(1,1)
qc.measure_all(add_bits=False)

Circuit:

     ┌───┐ ░ ┌─┐   
q_0: ┤ X ├─░─┤M├───
     └───┘ ░ └╥┘┌─┐
q_1: ──────░──╫─┤M├
           ░  ║ └╥┘
c: 2/═════════╩══╩═
              0  1 

Compiler options: {'optimization_level': 3, 'layout_method': 'trivial', 'seed_transpiler': 1000, 'routing_method': 'basic'}
Even after trying with multiple other optimization levels and routing_methods the issue still exists. Why is this happening ?
